# Hide an div element in scrolling when reached to an specific Id

Tags: javascript, html

I have a fix div and I need to hide it when it reaches to a specific id while I am scrolling down and show it back when I scrolled up.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post some code please. There are sites that teach you this kind of stuff (www.w3schools.com is one of them). CSS is most likely what you need, but I'd need more info to help you.

Comment: you can try to compare the div position (top) with the element you want to reach. Try use getBoundingClientRect() function: document.getElementById("idOfElment").getBoundingClientRect().top

Comment: @RicardoPontual Thank you.

I found this (check the link) but I need to change it somehow work with id instead of pixels and I cannot!
http://codepen.io/samora/pen/JKqyNE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.fn.isOnScreen = function () {
    var win = $(window);
    var viewport = {
        top: win.scrollTop(),
        left: win.scrollLeft()
    };
    viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
    viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();
    var bounds = this.offset();
    bounds.right = bounds.left + this.outerWidth();
    bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.outerHeight();
    return (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom));
};
```

And use it like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($('#sampleId').isOnScreen() == true) {
        $('.fixDiv').hide();
    }
    else{
        $('.fixDiv').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Mohammad!

I found this $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) { //use `this`, not `document`
        $('.fixedelement').css({
            'display': 'none'
        });
    }
});


but I wondering if I can tell once reached to  xxxxID, hide yyyyID?

Comment: @SasanMoradian If the answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted and vote it up :) thanks.

Comment: Thank you @Mohammad Reza this did the exact job!

Comment: One more question!
Is there a way, for example, to say if 50% of #sampleId was in screen then hide '.fixDiv' ?

Comment: Replace line 11 on first code block `bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.outerHeight();` with `bounds.bottom = bounds.top / 2 + this.outerHeight();` @SasanMoradian

Answer (score -1):

```
if($('#Div').is(':visible')){
    // add whatever code you want to run here.
}
```

Comment: your code tests whether an element is "visible" in the document. ie: whether the browser has rendered the element. It does not test whether the element is positioned within the view that is displayed to the user, and it is a once-off test that does not re-test as the user scrolls the page.